# Can I use X9C102 digitally controlled potentiometer on AC voltage?

Tags: potentiometer, dimmer, digital-potentiometer

I am working on a project to make a dimmer using the triac and a photocoupler, and I want to know if I can use a digital potentiometer to regulate the intensity of the light. I know it works for direct current, but will it work for AC?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, but with limitation. As the [datasheet](https://www.intersil.com/content/dam/Intersil/documents/x9c1/x9c102-103-104-503.pdf) says: +-5 V max. (page 4)

I would suggest using triac driver Optocoupler instead.